# Cythonize a partial differential equation integrator

Tags: python, numpy, cython, pde

I am trying to speed up a finite differences integrator for a partial differential equation using Cython. I am not sure what I need to do in order for Cython to work correctly with the numpy arrays.

The diffusion term function that I use is

```
def laplacian(var, dh2):
    """ (1D array, dx^2) -> laplacian(1D array)
    periodic_laplacian_1D_4th_order
    Implementing the 4th order 1D laplacian with periodic condition
    """
    lap = numpy.zeros_like(var)
    lap[1:]    = (4.0/3.0)*var[:-1]
    lap[0]     = (4.0/3.0)*var[1]
    lap[:-1]  += (4.0/3.0)*var[1:]
    lap[-1]   += (4.0/3.0)*var[0]
    lap       += (-5.0/2.0)*var

    lap[2:]   += (-1.0/12.0)*var[:-2]
    lap[:2]   += (-1.0/12.0)*var[-2:]
    lap[:-2]  += (-1.0/12.0)*var[2:]
    lap[-2:]  += (-1.0/12.0)*var[:2]

    return lap / dh2
```

And the rhs of the equations of the model are

```
from derivatives import laplacian

def dbdt(b,w,p,m,d,dx2):
    """ db/dt of Modified Klausmeier """
    return w*b**2 - m*b + laplacian(b,dx2)

def dwdt(b,w,p,m,d,dx2):
    """ dw/dt of Modified Klausmeier """
    return p - w - w*b**2 + d*laplacian(b,dx2)
```

How can I optimize those functions using Cython?

I have a repository on Github for my working code, that integrates the Gray-Scott model - [Gray-Scott model integrator](https://github.com/Omer80/POMK_simple).

Comment: What have you tried?  You'll get more help if you have specific problems implementing a `cython` version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use Cython efficiently, you should make all loops explicit and make sure `cython -a` shows as few Python calls as possible. A first try would be:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
def laplacian(double [::1] var, double dh2):
    """ (1D array, dx^2) -> laplacian(1D array)
    periodic_laplacian_1D_4th_order
    Implementing the 4th order 1D laplacian with periodic condition
    """
    cdef int n = var.shape[0]
    cdef double[::1] lap = np.zeros(n)
    cdef int i
    for i in range(0, n-1):
        lap[1+i] = (4.0/3.0)*var[i]
    lap[0]     = (4.0/3.0)*var[1]
    for i in range(0, n-1):
        lap[i]  += (4.0/3.0)*var[1+i]
    lap[n-1]   += (4.0/3.0)*var[0]
    for i in range(0, n):
        lap[i]       += (-5.0/2.0)*var[i]

    for i in range(0, n-2):
        lap[2+i]   += (-1.0/12.0)*var[i]
    for i in range(0, 2):
        lap[i]   += (-1.0/12.0)*var[n - 2 + i]
    for i in range(0, n-2):
        lap[i]   += (-1.0/12.0)*var[i+2]
    for i in range(0, 2):
        lap[n-2+i]  += (-1.0/12.0)*var[i]
    for i in range(0, n):
        lap[i]  /= dh2
    return lap
```

Now this gives you:

```
$ python -m timeit -s 'import numpy as np; from lap import laplacian; var = np.random.rand(1000000); dh2 = .01' 'laplacian(var, dh2)'
100 loops, best of 3: 11.5 msec per loop
```

while the NumPy code gave:

```
100 loops, best of 3: 18.5 msec per loop
```

Note that the Cython could be further optimized by merging loops etc.

I also tried with a customized (i.e. not committed in master) version of [Pythran](https://pythran.readthedocs.io) and without changing the original Python code, I had the same speedup as the Cython version, without the hassle of converting the code:

```
#pythran export laplacian(float [], float)
import numpy
def laplacian(var, dh2):
    """ (1D array, dx^2) -> laplacian(1D array)
    periodic_laplacian_1D_4th_order
    Implementing the 4th order 1D laplacian with periodic condition
    """
    lap = numpy.zeros_like(var)
    lap[1:]    = (4.0/3.0)*var[:-1]
    lap[0]     = (4.0/3.0)*var[1]
    lap[:-1]  += (4.0/3.0)*var[1:]
    lap[-1]   += (4.0/3.0)*var[0]
    lap       += (-5.0/2.0)*var

    lap[2:]   += (-1.0/12.0)*var[:-2]
    lap[:2]   += (-1.0/12.0)*var[-2:]
    lap[:-2]  += (-1.0/12.0)*var[2:]
    lap[-2:]  += (-1.0/12.0)*var[:2]

    return lap / dh2
```

Converted with:

```
$ pythran lap.py -O3
```

And I get:

```
100 loops, best of 3: 11.6 msec per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

So I guess I've figured it out, though I am not sure this is the most optimized way to do it:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cdef laplacian(np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] var,np.float64_t dh2):
    """ (1D array, dx^2) -> laplacian(1D array)
    periodic_laplacian_1D_4th_order
    Implementing the 4th order 1D laplacian with periodic condition
    """
    lap = np.zeros_like(var)
    lap[1:]    = (4.0/3.0)*var[:-1]
    lap[0]     = (4.0/3.0)*var[1]
    lap[:-1]  += (4.0/3.0)*var[1:]
    lap[-1]   += (4.0/3.0)*var[0]
    lap       += (-5.0/2.0)*var

    lap[2:]   += (-1.0/12.0)*var[:-2]
    lap[:2]   += (-1.0/12.0)*var[-2:]
    lap[:-2]  += (-1.0/12.0)*var[2:]
    lap[-2:]  += (-1.0/12.0)*var[:2]

    return lap / dh2
```

I have used the following setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize("derivatives_c.pyx")
)
```

Any advice on improving it is welcome..

Comment: That's not going to give you any good speedup, because most computations still run in Python there. Try `cython -a` on your code! To get the best out of cython, you should make the loop explicit...